# Comparision of P= F/A to Bernoulli's principle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

According to $P= \frac{F}{A}$, pressure reduces as area increase. But according  to Bernoulli's principle $P$ reduces as velocity  increase. But in nozzle velocity  at reduced area is high and pressure is low but according $P= \frac{F}{A}$, $P$ should be high.

Which one is correct or please explain in simple way?

Answer (score 2):

$P=\frac{F}{A}$ is merely the **definition** of pressure: force exerted per unit of surface area.

Bernoulli's principle, on the other hand, is an energy conservation equation for flowing fluids.

It's entirely pointless to compare the two.

> But in nozzle velocity at reduced area is high and pressure is low [...]

The reduced area in that context doesn't correspond to $A$ in the definitional equation.

Answer (score 1):

Agree that it is not wise to directly compare the two. Please use Bernoulli's equation to study or compare.